# traverse json data using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

Here is my xslt input:-

```
{
    "array1": [
        {
            "id": "banglore",
            "mappingData": [
                {
                    "name": "v1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "v2",
                    "Data": [
                        {
                            "idFromIndia": "0001"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I'm looking select `<xsl:value-of select="concat(?idFromIndia,'|')"/>`

I'm parsing input json using parse-json method;

`<xsl:variable name="input-as-map" select="parse-json($input)" as="map(*)"/>`

`$input-as-map?array1*mappingData`

I was trying to use wildcard method for traversing and i,e not working for me.

any suggestions would be helpful.......

Comment: It is not clear which result you want to output, please edit your question and show exactly which format and content your result should have.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, while I agree the question could be improved I don't think it makes sense to ask for a mandatory XML input if the question obviously processes JSON with XPath 3.1 and XSLT 3. Even in XSLT 2 you can start with a named template without the need for an XML input document.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, without minimal repro, both question and answer are unusable for anybody outside of the OP.

Comment: You need to elaborate a bit on which data in which format exactly you want to extract, in which context you use a snippet like `<xsl:value-of select="concat(?idFromIndia,'|')"/>` and which error you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<xsl:value-of select="$input-as-map?array1?*?mappingData?*?Data?*?idFromIndia"/>` should give you `0001` or `<xsl:value-of select="$input-as-map?array1?*?mappingData?*?Data?*?idFromIndia || '|'"/>` should give you `0001|`.